# SQL subquery aid

Tags: sql

I was wondering why do we have to do [1], instead of doing it like [2]? The question asks to calculate the number of matches in each country where total goals are more than 10

**[1]**

```
SELECT 
   c.name AS country,
   COUNT(s.id) AS matches
FROM country AS c
INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT country_id, id
   FROM match
   WHERE (home_goal + away_goal) >= 10) AS s
ON c.id = s.country_id
GROUP BY country
```

**[2]**

```
SELECT 
   c.name AS country,
   COUNT(m.id) AS matches
FROM country AS c
INNER JOIN match as m
ON c.id = m.country_id
WHERE (m.home_goal + m.away_goal) >= 10)
GROUP BY country
```

Comment: Why do you "have to do" ? Who/what says you can't (other than the syntax error of having too many `)` in [2])? Also not really sure why you select/count `c.id` - is it ever null for this inner join? Not all databases permit grouping by aliases created in the SELECT - is this MySQL?

Comment: Do subqueries when needed. It's not needed here.

Comment: Please add tag to identify specific database type sqlserver, MySQL, postgresql etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't, they are equivalent. Joining on subqueries is often done if you want to perform an aggregation (`GROUP BY`) or use window functions (`ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()`), but in this case, it's not necessary.

That being said, it also doesn't hurt. The query planner - which is the thing that executes the query for you in the most efficient way - is more than likely smart enough to recognise these as one and the same. So they should really not only produce the same results, but also get to those results in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Only different really is that option `1` is more useful when looking to perform some form of aggregation.

You can have a look at the query plan, both options will produce the same sort of plan (the query optimizer is smart enough to see that between queries). To see the difference in CPU and IO stats you can add this before the queries;

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON 
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
```

Comment: Those two commands only apply to Microsoft SQL Server, not to "SQL" (which the question is tagged with)

Answer (score 0):

The two queries are equivalent.  The second is preferable because it is simpler -- no subqueries needed.

In most databases, the two would have the same execution plans.  However, there are some notable differences.  Some databases (hi MySQL!) tend to materialize subqueries.  That can significantly hurt performance, because the optimizer loses information such as indexes and statistics.

Stick with the second version and ask whoever is recommending [1] over [2] to provide a clear justification.